# What the -exec in `find ... -exec ...` do?

Tags: find

I am learning searching and I'm confused this command.

```
find -name "*.swp" -exec rm {} ';'
```

Can you explain to me what this command means?

Comment: It deletes your swap files with the extension `.swp`. In my system using: `$ locate *.swp` tells me I have one swap file: `/etc/systemd/system/apt-daily.timer.d/..#override.confc1f37c0bd02ea65e.swp` This is different than the swap partition. Better answers can be provided if you include the link to what you were reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `exec`  command executes a specific command for each file found. It treats its arguments as a sub-process to execute. It is one of the most powerful and dangerous options provided by the `find`  command.

When you execute the above command, `find` will search for the given pattern in the directories and sub-directories. If found, it returns the filename with the relative path from the current directory.
For example:

```
  [guru@guru-Aspire~]$ touch temp1.swp temp2.swp temp3.swp   # Create 3 files.

  [guru@guru-Aspire~]$ find -name "*.swp" 
  ./temp2.swp
  ./temp3.swp
  ./temp1.swp
```

`find` takes all arguments after `-exec` as part of the command until the argument `;` is reached. `{}` is replaced with the filename searched by the `find` command.

The filename and `;` is needed to be separated so that it can be protected from the expansion. So, either we can escape it using `\;` or we can use or quoted  like `';'`

Answer (score 2):

`-exec` is an option of `find`. What's happening here is all files matching `*.swp` are removed one by one. `{}` is the full path and file name, not sure about trailing `;`. But the first term of find should be a directory or path to one. To learn more at the terminal type `man find`. `man` manuals can be searched using the `apropos command`.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than giving you a fish, here's how to fish: 
Type this in the console:

```
 man find
```

Or this (doens't work on all systems):

```
info find
```

Also check this out: [LDP: Bash for Beginners](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/index.html)  and learn to distinguish between a command and it's arguments ;)

Answer (score 0):

That line simply finds files recursively (in each subdirectory of command  issued) with **swp** extension and removes them. 
Here is a guide :http://www.ling.ohio-state.edu/~kyoon/tts/unix-help/unix-find-command-examples.htm#EX02
And this guide explains how to use `-exec` switch  with `find` command http://www.softpanorama.org/Tools/Find/using_exec_option_and_xargs_in_find.shtml